# Trouble Displaying Canvas Elements and Table Together in a PDF using Python and ReportLab

Tags: python, pandas, tkinter, reportlab

I'm currently working on a Python project where I need to generate a PDF document containing both canvas elements and a table. I'm using the ReportLab library, specifically the canvas module for canvas elements and the platypus module for the table.

The issue I'm facing is that only the table is being displayed in the generated PDF document, and the canvas elements are not visible. To give you more context, here are the steps I've taken and the problems encountered:

I've successfully created canvas elements (e.g., squares, lines, text) using the ReportLab canvas module. When I generate a PDF with only the canvas elements, they display correctly.

I've also successfully created a table using the platypus module and added it to the PDF document. When I generate a PDF with only the table, it appears as expected.

However, when I try to combine both canvas elements and the table in the same PDF document, only the table is displayed, and the canvas elements are missing.

Here's a simplified version of my code structure:

`

```
c = canvas.Canvas("output.pdf", pagesize=letter)
#canvas elements
c.showPage()
c.save()

# Create a PDF document
doc = SimpleDocTemplate("output.pdf", pagesize=letter)
elements = []

data = [["", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E"]]

# style table
table = Table(data, colWidths=col_widths, rowHeights=row_heights)
table.setStyle(TableStyle([
# Table style definitions...
]))

elements.append(table)
doc.build(elements)`
```

Successfully created canvas elements (e.g., squares, lines, text) using the ReportLab canvas module. When I generated a PDF with only the canvas elements, they displayed correctly.

Successfully created a table using the platypus module and added it to the PDF document. When I generated a PDF with only the table, it appeared as expected.

However, my goal is to combine both the canvas elements and the table on the same page within the same PDF document. Despite multiple attempts to adjust the code, including changing the order of element addition and coordinates, the result has consistently been that only the table is displayed, and the canvas elements are missing.

I've tried to import each element separately into the PDF document, and each element displays correctly when added individually. However, the challenge arises when I attempt to display both elements together on the same page.